# Dashed hook right arrow

Tags: diagrams, arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I'd like to use a dashed hook right arrow instead of a classic one in my LaTeX document, but I don't know how to create one. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
 \[
 \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=large]
  \Z \arrow{r}{\Phi} \arrow[twoheadrightarrow]{d} & R \\
  \Z_n \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ru}[swap]{\bar{\Phi}}
 \end{tikzcd}
 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\arrow[hookrightarrow,dashed]{ru}[swap]{\bar{\Phi}}`?

Comment: Easier: `\arrow[ru,hookrightarrow,dashed,swap,"\bar{\Phi}"]` (no need to remember the order of arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the keyword `dashed`. There's a simpler syntax available, which doesn't require to remember the argument positions.

Note that `hook` is sufficient. Similarly, `two heads` is simpler than `twoheadrightarrow`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=large]
  \Z \arrow[r,"\Phi"] \arrow[d,two heads] & R \\
  \Z_n \arrow[ru,hook,dashed,swap,"\bar{\Phi}"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `xymatrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
\mathbb{Z} \ar@{->>}[d] \ar[r]^{\Phi}& R \ar@{<--^{)}}[ld]^{\bar{\Phi}}\\
\mathbb{Z}}
\end{document}
```